# How to generate random numbers in Swift 2 Xcode 7?

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7, arc4random

Have updated to Xcode 7, which has Swift 2. I am creating an app. I need to generate random numbers. In Swift, there used to be arc4random(). But in Swift 2, arc4random() is not there. Instead, I am getting:

```
 arc4random_addrandom(<#T##UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>#>, <#T##Int32#>)
 arc4random_stir()
 arc4random_buf(<#T##UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>#>, <#T##Int#>)
```

How do I now generate random numbers? Any help would be appreciated a lot.

Comment: `rand()`, `rand_r(UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>)`, or `random()`, maybe.

Comment: Also discussed in the Apple Forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15643.

Answer (score 3):

`arc4random()` and `arc4random_uniform(_:)` are actually there, they're just not autocompleting for some reason. You can still use them!

Comment: I actually tried both but it is giving me an error : 'Expected pattern'. Now what shall I do?

Comment: What code exactly gives you this error? `let x = arc4random()` or `let x = arc4random_uniform(42)` work for me.

Comment: i tried :    var random : Int = Int(arc4random() % 2)

Comment: If you want a number that's either 0 or 1, you should use `arc4random_uniform(2)`.

Comment: Ok. But how do I use arc4random?Any idea?

Comment: Your code works for me with Xcode 7.2 (7C68).